# New version Python running on Old version Python TKINTER & TURTLE

Tags: python

So I have an application that uses Turtle (because its built in)... Runs perfectly, like 100 people are needing it and wanting to run it across many organizations.  It was written in version 3.6.5.  However these organizations have much older version 3.4.1 is one of them.  I can't share the code, nor can they easily upgrade their version in a timely manner....

The screen on their version opens and quickly closes, but in the 3.6.5 version it works perfectly.

My Question is:  What are some clues to look for a work around, or to trouble shoot the differences between these versions for tkinter --> turtle ?

Thanks in andvance.

Comment: I would use Pycharm and turn on the Python version inspection. Select all versions you want to support and hope it will highlight all differences

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo, only have IDLE, and each organization only has one version rather than 2 versions to check... however I can do a test at home with some generic code.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Anyway it's not exactly on-topic. Putting that aside, we simply can't help you with the information given. Maybe give us some code you need help with converting, but even then i'm not sure it's on-topic... Have you tried searching for some kind of "known issues" about moving versions with `tkinter`/`turtle`?

Comment: Just looking for advice on where to look... which you gave... I'm not sure what you mean about on-topic... I didn't see any topic when I asked the question... I'm going ot do the pycharm thing you suggested.. and am still looking.